# Remove item from listview

Tags: android, listview

How do you remove an item from a ListView in Android?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your underlying data source.

If you are using an `ArrayAdapter`, call `remove()` on the `ArrayAdapter` to remove the item, and it will vanish from the list.

If you are using `SimpleCursorAdapter`, remove the item from the database or content provider, then call `requery()` on the `Cursor`, and the item will vanish from the list.