# Android ListView Removing Item on click

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to remove an item from the list when I click on the selected item but I get an error on logcat saying that the removeViewAt method is not supported on AddapterView. Any idea of what I could use here in order to achieve this ?

Many thanks.
Here is my code.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int  position, long id)
        {
            listView.removeViewAt(position);
            listView.invalidateViews();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using arraylist to populate the listview

Comment: String Array mate : String[] Listitems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove item from listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671903/remove-item-from-listview)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> arrlist=new ArrayList<String>();
arrlist.add("A");
arrlist.add("B");
arrlist.add("C");
arrlist.add("D");

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
String[] items = { "Milk", "Butter", "Yogurt", "Toothpaste", "Ice Cream" };

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int  position, long id)
    {
        items.remove(position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: you cannot use remove with String[].

Comment: Remove this way:
String[] str_array = {"item1","item2","item3"};
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str_array));
list.remove("item2");
str_array = list.toArray(new String[0]);

Comment: I see your point but i get an error on my string[] saying that it cannot be assigned since it is defined in an enclosing type. any idea ?

Comment: Then use ArrayList<String> is the best way to use instead of String[]

Answer (score 0):

This fades away the clicked item using Animation, Requires `API level 16`

```
   private List<String> myList;
    File file;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listerX);
        myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        file = new File( directory + "/myAppCache/" );
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            myList.add( list[i].getName() );
        }
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0)
                        .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+item,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            }
                        });
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter); //Set all the file in the list.
    }
```

Comment: Nice one is it possible to remove the line, not just fade out ?

Answer (score 0):

you are populate list with any array or collection item
Then remove item at position of clicked position.
And now notify adapter by calling adapter.notifydatasetchange();
Enjoy your code